# Plot data from Excel in Python

Tags: excel, pandas, matplotlib

The code I have to read and plot data from my excel file is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
excel_file = 'file1.xlsx'
file1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

file1.head()

plt.plot(x,y1,y2)

plt.xlabel('wavelenghts')
plt.ylabel('reflectivity')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show
```

It works.

The questions are:

1. I have more columns, but when I want to add `y3, y4,...` I get the error that `y3 is undefined.`
2. In legend I want to change the name of `y1` to `CK4/5-PCA82500` and others as well. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f, ax = figure()
plt.plot(file1.x,file1.y1,label='')
plt.plot(file1.x,file1.y2)
plt.plot(file1.x,file1.y3)
.....

plt.xlabel('wavelenghts')
plt.ylabel('reflectivity')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show
```

Comment: Thank you @gen. It worked. Do you if alo I can change the name of my legends in the figure?

Comment: You just need to change/add "label" in plt.plot() like I did in second row of codes